# How does the cb:eval preprocessor work in CruiseControl.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to calculate a value in my ccnet.config file.  So I tried this:

```
  <cb:eval prio="$(BasePriority)+$(Priority)" />

    <project name="test" queue="test" queuePriority="$(prio)">
...
```

But this gave me an error that eval needs to have the "expr" attribute.  How do I name the output of the eval so I can reference it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an example in another question on stack overflow.  Here is how its done:

```
<cb:define name="prio">
  <cb:eval expr="$(BasePriority)+$(Priority)" />
</cb:define>

<project name="test" queue="test" queuePriority="$(prio)">
```